# Is there a reason to use udev when I have mdev?

Tags: embedded-linux, hotplugging

I'm running an embedded linux system which is based to TI´s Arago base image. This distribution comes with both mdev and udev. It doesn't seem like either of them are configured, so I'm about to choose between one of them. The system is pretty powerful (ARM A8 1 GHz), so cpu power is not really an issue.

So, is there any reason for choosing udev when mdev is available? Are there scenarios that mdev is unable to cope with?

Comment: Oh, mdev is busybox's mini-udev.

Comment: Hi @Kotte, compare to mdev, udev consumes quite a lot of memory space. If you are seeking for stability hotplug, I would recommend you to use udev, we experienced some race condition with mdev (no device node was created when doing hotplug)